# Appending data to SQL table in QGIS by matching field names

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

In QGIS 3+, is there a plugin that allows you append data from one feature into another without needing to move columns around, and map columns automatically based on field name?

I want to merge between two layers where both layers have the same column names, e.g. Feature 1: Length into Feature 2: Length. We currently change the order of columns of sourch feature to match the destination feature.

Comment: What is the tool you are using now? (If any)

Comment: You don't need a plugin - that's how it works out of the box, when you copy paste between layers the attributes are matched by name not column order (they probably need to have the same data type as well as the same name).  Edit: I see you might be using the Merge Vector Layers command - could I suggest copy paste if it works for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the refresher. I completely forgot that method. It works.